# How can I apply VSCode language specific settings to files created in Django projects in virtual environment?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, settings

When I create django project in virtual environment, language specific settings does not apply to files newly created in the project.

Here is relevant part of settings.json:

```json
{

    ...

    // language specific settings
    "[html]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
        "cSpell.fixSpellingWithRenameProvider": false,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },

    ...

}
```

Here are the steps that I take when I create project:

```
python -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install django==3.2.18
pip freeze > requirements.txt

django-admin startproject TheProject .
python manage.py startapp app_1
python manage.py startapp app_2
```

I add application names to `INSTALLED_APPS` list, give `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` for TEMPLATES["DIR"] in settings.py. Then I create an html file :

```
code templates/base.html
```

`base.html` has 4 spaces for a tab.

Trying it without virtual environment didn't work.
The setting is properly applied to html files created outside the project: They have 2 spaces for a tab.

What is going on?
How can I make language specific settings properly applied to files inside django project?

Comment: what is your exact workspace folder/file organization, where is the `.vscode` folder with the `settings.json` file and the where is the virt env

Comment: **DON'T** create your project files **IN** the virtual environment folder

Comment: settings.json in the ~Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json. I didn't create project in venv/.

Comment: `venv/` is outside the project, and I can't find `.vscode` folder(MacOS).

Comment: django extension uses a different languageID for HTML files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding django-html specific settings seems to work for me :

```json
{

    ...

    // language specific settings
    
    ...

    "[django-html]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "other": true,
            "comments": true,
            "strings": true,
        },
        "editor.tabSize": 2,   // <- this line sets tab size
    },

    ...

}
```